# Get latitude and longitude from Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I want to get Latitude and Longitude during mouseover event of google map. I have written following code,

```
  GEvent.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), "mousemove", function(e) {
    alert('mousemove:'+e.lat()+':'+e.lng());
  });
```

It gives me "undefined" output. What can be the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a [`Listener`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapsEventListener), rather than a `DomListener`.

Also, the event will contain a single field called `latLng` which will have the getters `lat` and `lng`.

Try:

```
GEvent.addListener(document.getElementById("map"), "mousemove", function(e) {
    alert('mousemove:'+e.latLng.lat()+':'+e.latLng.lng());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got answer as follow

```
GEvent.addListener(map, 'click', function(overlay, point) {
     var latLngStr = "Lat = " + point.y + ", Long = " + point.x;
     map.openInfoWindow(point, latLngStr);
     document.getElementById("latbox").value=point.y;
     document.getElementById("lonbox").value=point.x;
});
```